# Mouse swipe in Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp

I have decided to use list view with  SwipeControl at each item,
first of all I have opened the AppUiBasics example provided by Microsoft, and I have found that I cannot slide any element which supports "sliding". I wonder if mouse pressed and moved is recognized as swipe bcos "SlidableListItem_RightCommandRequested" event never happens.

Can this "Swipe" movement be simulated with a mouse or it works only with sensor displays? What am I doing wrong or did i miss something?

[image: swiping problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported, here is an answer
https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView/issues/1
there is an alternative for desktop 
https://github.com/brookshi/LLMListView